# Yii CGridView rendered inside CJuiDialog won't be filtered or ordered

Tags: ajax, yii, cgridview, cjuidialog

I'm rendering a CGridView inside a CJuiDialog, and that's working fine.

My problem is, every time i click a column header to sort records, the page changes (the url is the url of the view rendered with renderPartial through ajax) and the request is not ajax ( `Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest` inside the controller is false).

Also, if i filter any field, nothing happens.

How can I let the user sort or filter the CGridView?

OR:
Is there another way to let the user choose a Foreign Key field through a CGridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

When you call renderPartial you must set the 3rd parameter = FALSE and the 4th parameter = TRUE.

```
$this->renderPartial('ajax_view',array(
            'model'=>$model,
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            ),false,TRUE);
```

From the official documentation:

**$return**     *boolean*   whether the rendering result should be returned instead of being displayed to end users
**$processOutput**  *boolean*   whether the rendering result should be postprocessed using processOutput.

And the MOST IMPORTANT TWEAK:
Inside the view rendered with renderPartial you must add:

```
Yii::app()->clientscript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
```

The page is reloaded simply 'cause jquery was loaded multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

This issue probably is happening because a javascript error, or the click function on your code is being override (and not returning false). Could you show your code?

Comment: There are no javascript errors, looking fot the solution over the net, i found out clicking on a column header reloads the page even in the standard CGridView (but the user doesn't notice it). But that's my problem, i got to prevent that page loading

Comment: I've never seen this information before. The click on a column header calls a ajax, and never reloads the page. this can only happens if this isn't returning false, and by default it actually does: [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/demos/blog/index.php/post/admin)